# How can I solve the following phasor analysis question?

Tags: inductor, kirchhoffs-laws, phasor

[image: Phasor Analysis]

How can I solve part B?

Obviously, since the two sources have different frequencies I started off by killing the voltage source (short-circuit) and then tried to apply KCL.

My goal was to find the voltage on the node that is to the left of the inductor and then use voltage division to find V_o but the 1 ohm resistor that is parallel to the current source is causing a problem. I would source transform it to bring it in series with the transformed voltage source and existing 1 ohm resistor but the current through it is needed because there is also a CDVS that depends on i_x.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show us all of your work. We need to see that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: Laplace transform + Thevenin works quite well

Answer (score 0):

EE&O

**> How can I solve part B?**

For solving, first, take a look at this. Simulation of the circuit.
A good starting point was ... you wanted to apply the "superposition principle".

Are all the devices all "linear"? It can be applied.
Now, you see the result. So apply KVL and/or KCL as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realized I_x was just equal to the voltage on the node between the current source and the 1Ohm resistor which allowed me to solve it easily!

Comment: Ok. Make your own answer with all the details of calculus ...

Comment: For who downvoted ... Not useful?